# Outlook Rules work Automatically but not manually in "Run Rules Now" dialog

Tags: rules, microsoft-outlook-2016

I have created a ton of outlook rules since recently i've been added to a group which gets, in my opinion, spammed with emails like new stores opening, reports and emails about problems unrelated to my department or location (ie. a celebratory party for the completion or UAT....which is being held in another state) and i have made these rules to that emails that actually require my attention aren't buried under those that don't (if a failed report required my attention to fix i am contacted to fix it so i can monitor the failures).

when a new email comes into my inbox i make the rule to move it to another folder. these rules work fine automatically but when i run it manually it doesn't work

[image]

with the screenshot above if i hit "Run Now" for the single rule i have selected (i double check) it doesn't do anything and the email in my inbox i expect to move doesn't, however i made this rule 24 hours ago and i know it's working as the emails that was recived and matched the rule did get sent to the folder as expected. however i have a very similar rule which does work when i run it in this dialog when it's selected

[image]

But as you can see the only difference is the "New Item Alert" action but it's not this because i add it to the rule i'm tyring to run and no chnage

So **why can't I run my rule manually in "Run Rules Now"**

Comment: Click Browse... next to "Run in Folder" and ensure that the correct Inbox is selected. I have more than one.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I've checked that Inbox is selected. Smells like a bug...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried highlighting the specific emails you want the rule to run on (click on the top email, shift + click the last email) in your inbox, then go to Rules, Manage Rules & Alerts, Run Rules Now